# Multiple instances of Word 2013 open at boot after Win 10 rollout

Tags: windows-10, microsoft

We have one user who is getting 51 Word windows at boot - it's ridiculous! Several others are getting 10-20 instances, as well.

I've gone through multiple workstations to make sure nothing is in the Startup folder or set to run at boot for that, but no dice. We don't have anything like that in GP, either.

Any suggestions for where to look?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and perform a boot trace (Options -> Enable Boot Logging) or start process monitor from another account in the computer and while the capture is running, log on with the user's account and then stop the capture.

You will be able to see the process tree (Tools -> Process Tree) so you will be able to see "who" launched Word.